# How can I write svg to a Highcharts.Renderer object?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for charting and I love it.  I have a page that has 4 charts on it.  I'd like to use the Highcharts.Renderer to combine all 4 charts into one Renderer object to print them and/or export them as one image.  I can see how to add a svg image from disk to the Highcharts.Renderer, but it seems like a wasted step to write the svg and then read it again, since I already have the svg in my doc.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine all 4 charts into one object to print or export them as one image
the following URL demonstrates a perfect solution http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/1/